# How many ways of creating java object dynamically at run-time without using any framework

Tags: java, object, dynamically-generated

I would like to know if there are any other ways of creating java object dynamically beside the follow ways without using any framework.

Code block is as such

```
Object obj = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

and

```
Object obj = Class.forName(className).getConstructor(ParameterType.class).newInstance(parameter);
```

Comment: `MyObject obj = new MyObject();` :)

Comment: Why without using any framework? Someone wrote those frameworks and so can you.

Answer (score 3):

There are four different ways:

**1. Using new keyword**
This is the most common way to create an object in java. I read somewhere that almost 99% of objects are created in this way.

```
MyObject object = new MyObject();
```

**2. Using Class.forName()**
If we know the name of the class & if it has a public default constructor we can create an object in this way.

```
MyObject object = (MyObject) Class.forName("subin.rnd.MyObject").newInstance();
```

**3. Using clone()**
The clone() can be used to create a copy of an existing object.

```
MyObject anotherObject = new MyObject(); 
MyObject object = anotherObject.clone();
```

**4. Using object deserialization**
Object deserialization is nothing but creating an object from its serialized form.

```
ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(anInputStream ); 
MyObject object = (MyObject) inStream.readObject();
```

[Reference](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/different-ways-to-create-objects/)

Answer (score 0):

You can (ab)use the facotry method pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern